# Menu creation and the ANR crash with LibGDX

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl, libgdx

Some users on my app are experiencing ANR crashes at start up as UI thread-max-pause time is manufacture set it's crucial to avoid UI thread blocking events.

My problem is this and I'm not sure how to fix it:

OpenGL requires that you need to load textures on the UI thread.
Now I'm loading textures using a async class at the start and loading them in, this works fine my problem is my UI engine creates all the screens at the start and an entire map of the world with each country (takes 1.7ish seconds on Nexus 5, a lot longer on slower devices).

The following requires OpenGL context:

```
sprite = SpriteLoader.getInstance().getSprite(textureName);
//and in getSprite
return new Sprite(this.assetManagerInternal.get(textureName, Texture.class));
```

So I have to create all my menus using the UI thread

```
Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable()
```

As each screen:

```
PopupManager.getInstance().createPopupViews();
//Somehow tell Android/Application were still alive.
TraitController.getInstance().createTraitViews();
```

Problem is this blocks the UI thread and sometimes (but not always on the same device) causes an ANR crash.

I can't think of any ideas to get around this. I've tried running it in another thread then posting each sprite to the UI thread but this causes lots of issues with thread synchronisation.

The ideal solution which I can't find would be to notify the Android process that my application is still running after each screen, does this exist?